# How to add Control over GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I haved drawn a round Rectangle using OnPaint event:

```
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            GraphicsPath path = RoundedRectangle.Create(5, 5, 20, 20);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
        }
```

and i want to draw a control over that rectangle . e.g: a `TextBox`

Question: Is there a way to know the `Location` or the `Point` of GraphicsPath to set my control over it?

Answer (score 1):

So you want something that looks like this:

[image]

Mine is set up as a custom class that inherits from control and has a custom `OnPaint` to get the rounded edges:

```
class RoundedText : Control
{
    //Code
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code for rounded edges
    }
}
```

Then to get the textbox to show up, I add the TextBox to the control, just as I would a form:

```
class RoundedText : Control
{
    public RoundedText()
    {
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Left = 10;
        t.Top = 1;
        this.Controls.Add(t);
    }
}
```

This way, the TextBox is always placed relative to the rectangle, so you don't need to worry about getting the position of the path.